# How to update table column using WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `postcode`. It has a column `postcode` which contains 4/5 digit integers (i.e. 66770, 66670, 3090, 6660). I want to run a query which prepends `0` to all the fields which contains 4 digit values (i.e. change '6660' to '06660').
I tried this query but it says `0 rows affected` and no changes are made.

```
UPDATE postcode SET postcode = Concat('0', postcode) WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(postcode) = 4;
```

Did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
UPDATE postcode set postcode = CONCAT('0', postcode) where LENGTH(postcode)=4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `UPDATE postcode SET postcode = REPLACE(postcode, N'____', 0);`

Here i just replace everything with 4 characters to 0 (there are 4 underscores)

Answer (score 1):

If all your records are 4 or 5 you don't need the where clause and

```
UPDATE postcode SET postcode = RPAD(TRIM(postcode), 5, '0')
```

Should do the work. However if you have records with 3 digits and you don't wanna update these you need to add the where to filter

```
UPDATE postcode 
SET postcode = LPAD(TRIM(postcode), 5, '0') 
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(postcode) = 4;
```

I am using `TRIM()` in case the `postcode` field had some empty space at the end.

Comment: Your first answer appends the `0` not prepend. And when I changed `RPAD` to `LPAD`, the result is still the same, nothing happens.